# selenium locate element with xpath

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath

Firebug gives me this for an element inputfiled I want to fill in:

```
<label for="form:composite:tabView:ssn">Fødselsnummer</label>
```

Tried this in my selenium script:

```
 WebElement velger = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='form:composite:tabView:ssn']"));
```

Next I do this:

```
  velger.sendKeys(new String[]{"27017833176"});
```

And then:

```
WebElement sokknapp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"form:composite:tabView:searchSSN\"]"));
    sokknapp.click();
```

To click the serach button.

However when looking at the browser during replay I can se that the "sendkeys" does not work but the button click does work (the inputfield gets red because I press the button for searching without content in the inputfield).

Is there something wrong with this:

```
velger.sendKeys(new String[]{"27017833176"});
```

Comment: Why are you using a label as an input? That's likely your problem. You should always try and use a valid HTML element for the task at hand, i.e. an `<input/>`

Comment: Also your trying to select by id `@id='form:composite:tabView:ssn` but that label doesn't have an id, it has a `for` attribute?

Comment: Show `HTML` of input element. `Label` is just some kind of name for input field

Comment: So how would you write the code
WebElement velger = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='form:composite:tabView:ssn']"));
 given your input?

Comment: the firebug output:
<div class="text-center search-container ssn-search">
<div class="form-group required">
<label for="form:composite:tabView:ssn">Fødselsnummer</label>
<input id="form:composite:tabView:ssn" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputmask ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all form-control focusable" type="text" aria-required="true" name="form:composite:tabView:ssn" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
<span id="form:composite:tabView:ssnNameError"></span>

Comment: @MagnusJensen, yes, this should work. Did you try it?

Comment: WebElement velger = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='form:composite:tab‌​View:ssn']")); did not work.

Comment: What do you mean "did not work"? What is exact result? Exception?

Comment: sorry, the log says:  Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='form:composite:tab‌​‌​View:ssn']"}

Comment: and given that my location of the button works I have almost similar code for the two accept the 'id' is replaced by the 'for':
 WebElement velger = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@for=\"form:composite:tab‌​‌​View:ssn\"]"));
        velger.sendKeys(new String[]{"27017833176"});
        WebElement sokknapp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"form:composite:tabView:searchSSN\"]"));

Comment: not abel to find the element still dough..

Answer (score 0):

`Unable to locate element` might means that you need some time to wait before handle element:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var velger = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("form:composite:ta‌​b‌​‌​View:ssn")));
```

Also I'm not sure about correctness of `velger.sendKeys(new String[]{"27017833176"});`. Try to send simple string:

```
velger.sendKeys("27017833176");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem (or solution) was that I missed i clear() function before sendkeys.

```
 velger.clear();
    velger.sendKeys("27017833176");
```

Comment: This could not be a problem in your case as you might need to use `clear()` method only if text already present in input field. Your problem was in incorrect content - `new String[]{"27017833176"}`